# Why not access update DB in jax-rs web service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jax-rs

I create Jax-Rs web service using following technology. but can't update DB

*Technology Used*

- Java 1.8
- Eclipse Luna IDE
- RestEasy-3.0.8.Final
- Spring-Framework-3.2.11.RELEASE
- Hibernate-4.2.15.Final
- Apache Maven 3.2.1
- Apache Tomcat 8.0.23
- MySql-Connector-Java-5.1.32

This is spring-hibernate-resteasy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!-- to activate annotations in beans already registered in the ApplicationContext -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- scans packages to find and register beans within the application context -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.resteasy.series.spring.hibernate" />

<!-- turn on spring transaction annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.resteasy.series.spring.hibernate.model.Customer</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- dataSource configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

I follow this article create for web service [link](http://www.benchresources.net/resteasy-jax-rs-web-service-integrating-with-spring-and-hibernate-orm-framework/).

Why is this happen to me? How to solve in this scenario. I can get data From DB, but can't update DB.

Comment: And where is the code that "updates" DB?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "can't update DB"? Do you get an error? An exception?

Comment: http://www.benchresources.net/resteasy-jax-rs-web-service-integrating-with-spring-and-hibernate-orm-framework/ this same as my **Update code** you try this example. I try it same way.

Comment: There are can't sent data into DB. this is my Problem.